# PHP MySQL Request not working when using a variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, http-post

the MySQL request works fine when I do it like this:

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE "test"';
```

but when I use a variable like this, it gives an error:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE'.$username;
```

Error:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function `fetch_assoc()` on boolean...

`var_dump` of `$username` gives:

```
 string(4) "test"
```

Thanks for your help!

Full code so far:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
var_dump($username);

include 'data.php';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "'.$username.'"';
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
$row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();

echo $row1["ID"];
```

Comment: Add a space: `" LIKE " . $value` and prepare for more errors and sql-ijection.

Comment: and wrap var in quotes

Comment: Add some error reporting to your sql queries, your syntax is invalid. Also you should use parameterized/prepared queries to mitigate sql injection vulnerabilities

Comment: Use this $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE %'.$username.'%';

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is incorrect:-> use this.... $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE"'.$username.'"';

Comment: Still invalid, missing a space between like and the username

Comment: This solves the error problem, but doesn't give back a dataset fro the database..

Comment: Because you did not add $res = mysql_query($sql) did u?

Comment: After that fetch array using $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)

Comment: $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "'.$username.'"';
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
$row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();

Comment: Are you using pdo?

Comment: You are using $username for mysli connection too.. Change variable name

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lakhvir kumar! I used a variable name twice and also had some syntax mistakes..

Changed $username, now it works..